# New phone making me start a new game

Tags: iphone

Got me a new phone New iPhone  6+ is  Making me start a new game but I already have a game I'm level 83 how can I get my game back

Comment: It would help to know which game—some games store data in Game Center (where you can just sign in), but others store it on your phone (where you'd have to restore from backup).

Answer (score 1):

Your best option would probably be to backup your old phone and restore the backup on the new phone.  This should copy save data from one device to the other.

Answer (score -1):

Even some games are linked to facebook .. So all you have to do is sign into face book abd link the game to it ..